# Call code behind method from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following aspx code where I am calling a method from code behind. The result of the code behind method is not getting rendering in the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Src="LeftMenuSrce.aspx.cs"  Inherits="LeftMenuSrce" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:Table ID ="LeftMenuTable" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ID="LeftMenuSrce" OnDataBinding="_getLeftMenuSrc"></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is my cs code:

```
public class LeftMenuSrce : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell LeftMenuSrce;
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table LeftMenuTable;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            LeftMenuSrce.DataBind();            
        }

        protected string _getLeftMenuSrc()
        {
            string leftMenu;
            leftMenu = "LeftMenuNew.aspx";
            return leftMenu;
        }
    }
```

Even I have tried div instead of asp:tables, but nothing was working.

```
<div>
<%#_getLeftMenuSrce()%>
</div>
```

Any clues to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Please note I have referred below links, but nothing helped me.

[How to call a code-behind method from aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754016/how-to-call-a-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page)

[Call code behind method from aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079480/call-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page)

[ASP.NET - Use variable in .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344650/asp-net-use-variable-in-aspx-page)

Comment: That's not how the `OnDataBinding` method works. It shouldn't return a value, it has to have an `EventArgs` parameter, and it should handle assigning the value properly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.ondatabinding(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%=_getLeftMenuSrc() %>`

Comment: <%=... %> is used to evaluate the expression right? I need to bind data from LeftMenuNew.aspx where I have some logic being written. I have referred this link for <%= ..%> http://forums.asp.net/t/1313014.aspx?How+to+work+with+server+tags+in+aspx+html+page

Comment: If you want to put the result returned then two ways 1. Put content to be rendered in UserControl with Use ContentPlaceHolder,use that usercontrol in both pages. Another way is to use HttpClient in your codebehind make request to page, read the result and render.

Comment: Content to be resused should be placed UserControl and Use the UserControl where you are using div. This is better way to achive what you want to. Another way is in your codebehind function using HttpClient create request to the page (This approach is used for external pages), Client will return the content of the webpage or any http request. you can return that content.

Comment: Here is the example of Httpclient http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must implement your method "_getLeftMenuSrc()" as an event handler.

Example:

```
protected void _getLeftMenuSrc(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

I guess you simply try to write some text into your `TableCell LeftMenuSrce`.
One way to do this is writing a OnPreRender event handler like this:

```
protected void TableCell1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableCell1.Text = "My text in a cell !!";
    // Hint: 'sender' is your table cell ;-)
    ((TableCell) sender).Text = "My other text in that cell !!";
}
```

An other way is to fill all your tables cells within the Page_Load event. Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableCell1.Text = "My text in a cell !!";
}
```

BTW: Don't use tables to build a navigation ;-). Try  this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp